# Value present in more than one table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables. All of them have a column - id. I want to find if there is any value that is common across the tables. Assuming that the tables are named a.b and c, if id value 3 is present is a and b, there is a problem. The query can/should exit at the first such occurrence. There is no need to probe further. What I have now is something like

```
( select id from a intersect select id from b ) 
union 
( select id from b intersect select id from c ) 
union
( select id from a intersect select id from c )
```

Obviously, this is not very efficient. Database is PostgreSQL, version 9.0

id is not unique in the individual tables. It is OK to have duplicates in the same table. But if a value is present in just 2 of the 3 tables, that also needs to be flagged and there is no need to check for existence in he third table, or check if there are more such values. One value, present in more than one table, and I can stop.

Comment: What should be the result if a value is present in b and c but not in a?

Comment: is `id` unique in any given table?

Comment: @Bohemian - No. Updated question

Comment: @wildplasser - if any value is present in more than one table, it is a situation that needs to be corrected. It is OK to have duplicates in the same table. So b and c, not a, also needs to be flagged.

Answer (score 1):

Although `id` is not unique within any given table, it should be unique *across* the tables; a `union` of  `distinct id` should be unique, so:

```
select id from (
  select distinct id from a
  union all
  select distinct id from b
  union all
  select distinct id from c) x
group by id
having count(*) > 1
```

Note the use of `union all`, which preserves duplicates (plain `union` removes duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a simple `join`:

```
select a.id
from a join
     b
     on a.id = b.id join
     c
     on a.id = c.id
limit 1;
```

If you have a query that uses `union` or `group by` (or `order by`, but that is not relevant here), then you need to process *all* the data before returning a single row.  A `join` can start returning rows as soon as the first values are found.

An alternative, but similar method is:

```
select a.id
from a
where exists (select 1 from b where a.id = b.id) and
      exists (select 1 from c where a.id = c.id);
```

If `a` is the smallest table and `id` is indexes in `b` and `c`, then this could be quite fast.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select id from
(
select distinct id, 1 as t from a
union all
select distinct id, 2 as t from b
union all
select distinct id, 3 as t from c
) as t
group by id having count(t)=3
```

Answer (score 0):

- It is OK to have duplicates in the same table.
- The query can/should exit at the first such occurrence.

---

```
SELECT 'OMG!' AS  danger_bill_robinson
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM  a,b,c -- maybe there is a place for old-style joins ...
        WHERE a.id = b.id
        OR a.id = c.id
        OR c.id = b.id
        );
```

---

Update: it appears the optimiser does not like carthesian joins with 3 OR conditions. The below query is a bit faster:

```
SELECT 'WTF!' AS danger_bill_robinson
WHERE exists (select 1 from a JOIN b USING (id))
  OR exists (select 1 from a JOIN c USING (id))
  OR exists (select 1 from c JOIN b USING (id))
    ;
```